# ActiveMQ JMSXGroupID does not work as expected

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp

I use this script to start ActiveMQ locally:

```
docker run -p 61616:61616 -p 61614:61614 -p 8161:8161 -it -v conf:/opt/activemq/conf -v data:/opt/activemq/data rmohr/activemq
```

It starts AMQ version 5.15.6. I connect with AMQ with STOMP over websockets (v1.2).
Through web console in my "test" queue I create two messages both with same group "test_grp". I start two processes and each one runs same logic:

- connect
- subscribe to "/queue/test" with `activemq.prefetchSize: 1` and `ack: client-individual` headers
- on new message sleep 5sec and send ack for the message

Both processes receive messages immediately while the second message should be received by the same process or at least it should be received after the first one is ACKed.

Also if I start only one process/subscription with `activemq.prefetchSize: 2` header then this process receives two messages immediately instead sequentially after first one is ACKed.

So it seems that JMSXGroupID does not have any effect on how messages are processed. Is it possible that something is not configured correctly on broker side?

I am sure messages are not ACKed automatically because they are still in the queue until consumer ACKs them.

---

After some testing I figured out that grouping across two consumers works. However still for one consumer with `activemq.prefetchSize: 2` it receives two messages from same group immediately. Is this expected behaviour? If yes then it seems that if someone want to process messages in order he must set `activemq.prefetchSize` to `1` on subscription?

Here is piece of code to test (Node.js 12.x and requires packages `@stomp/stompjs` and `websocket`):

```js
Object.assign(global, { WebSocket: require('websocket').w3cwebsocket });
const { Client } = require('@stomp/stompjs');

function createClient() {
  return new Client({
    brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600',
  });
}

function createLog(name) {
  return (...str) => console.log.apply(console, [`${new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1]} <${name}>`, ...str]);
}

function createConsumer(name) {
  const log = createLog(name);
  const client = createClient();

  client.onConnect = () => {
    log('CLIENT_CONNECTED');
    client.subscribe('/queue/test', (msg) => {
      log('RECEIVED_MESSAGE');
      setTimeout(() => {
        msg.ack();
        log('ACKED_MESSAGE');
      }, 10000);
    }, {
      'activemq.prefetchSize': '2',
      ack: 'client-individual',
    });
  }

  client.activate();
}

function publishMessages() {
  const log = createLog();
  const client = createClient();

  client.onConnect = () => {
    client.publish({
      destination: '/queue/test',
      headers: {
        persistent: true,
        JMSXGroupID: 'grp',
      },
      body: 'test message 1',
    });
    client.publish({
      destination: '/queue/test',
      headers: {
        persistent: true,
        JMSXGroupID: 'grp',
      },
      body: 'test message 2',
    });
  };

  client.activate();
}

createConsumer('A');
createConsumer('B');

setTimeout(() => {
  publishMessages();
}, 2000);
```

Output:

```
22:50:03.196Z <B> CLIENT_CONNECTED
22:50:03.199Z <A> CLIENT_CONNECTED
22:50:05.195Z <B> RECEIVED_MESSAGE <-- ~same time
22:50:05.198Z <B> RECEIVED_MESSAGE <-- ~same time
22:50:15.196Z <B> ACKED_MESSAGE
22:50:15.198Z <B> ACKED_MESSAGE
```

---

Here are headers received by STOMP client (there is no any group info):

```
headers: {
    timestamp: '1580796287376',
    persistent: 'true',
    'message-id': 'ID:04f803c080ac-46709-1580756713304-3:66:-1:1:2',
    priority: '4',
    subscription: 'sub-0',
    ack: 'ID:04f803c080ac-46709-1580756713304-70:2',
    destination: '/queue/test',
    expires: '0',
    'content-length': '14'
  },
```

---

This is strange because it seems that JMSXGroupID does not guarantee processing order in group. It only guarantees that messages will be delivered to same consumer in same order but message B can be delivered to consumer before it ACKs message A (or even "starts" processing A) (assuming here that consumer has `activemq.prefetchSize > 1`). I don't understand this because since consumer uses `ack: client-individual` mode that means that until consumer sends ACK message **can not** be treated as delivered by broker. So why broker sends message from group for which it does know if previous message from same group was delivered? Maybe it's possible somehow to configure ActiveMQ broker to prevent doing this?

Other solution would be to somehow receive JMSXGroupID header along with a message from broker which does not work (at least not in STOMP) - in such case broker could have local mini-queue(s) to locally order messages from same group in correct order.

My use case is that I want to have a queue that is a input channel for a microservice (/queue/my-service). Other microservices will send messages/events/commands to it. Some of them may have JMSXGroupID, others may not. What I want is to have single subscription with some concurrency (`activemq.prefetchSize > 1`). So if 6 messages (A1, A2, A3, B, C, D) are rceived "at once" and three of them  are from same group (A1, A3, A3) and other are in different groups or not in any group at all then consumer should process in parallel:

- A1 -> A2 -> A3 (sequentialy)
- B
- C
- D

---

I reported bug (it looks like a bug as @Justin Bertram mentioned) regarding missing JMSXGroupID header in a message here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-7395

Comment: I would first confirm that the `JMSXGroupID` property is being set correctly on the message being sent. Perhaps instead of relying on the web console you could write a simple producer and then share that code in your question so it could be validated and even tested by others. It's usually tedious and error prone to conduct tests using GUI tools.

Comment: It would also help to supply the full code of your consumer as well.

Comment: Thanks, something was wrong with testing with GUI as you said. I updated my question - still there is a case with one consumer and `activemq.prefetchSize: 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the expected behavior. If you set `activemq.prefetchSize` to a value greater than 1 then the broker will dispatch more than 1 message to the client at a time. Since stompjs will invoke the callback function you pass to `subscribe` whenever it receives a message then you'll have to control  acknowledgement order yourself or simply set `activemq.prefetchSize` to `1`.

To address some of your specific points...

> ...JMSXGroupID does not guarantee processing order in group. It only guarantees that messages will be delivered to same consumer in same order...

That's exactly correct. Grouping messages with the `JMSXGroupID` header only guarantees that messages in the same group will be delivered to a particular consumer in the order in which they were received by the broker. Once that is done the acknowledgement order is up to the client itself.

Generally speaking it is assumed that message processing concurrency comes from multiple concurrent consumers rather than a single consumer (or a set of consumers) which processes messages concurrently itself. In this general case delivering grouped messages to a single consumer is enough to guarantee order since it will be processing messages serially.

> So why broker sends message from group for which it does know if previous message from same group was delivered?

The broker sends multiple messages from the same group because you've asked it to by setting `activemq.prefetchSize` to a value greater than 1.

Comment: It seems that ActiveMQ does not send JMSXGroupID along with the message to the STOMP client. This means that we can't detect if a received message(s) should be processed sequentially or not with other received messages. So it seems that if we set `activemq.prefetchSize > 1` and we expect any messages to be grouped then we have to locally process and ACK all received messages sequentially (even not grouped ones). Is that right? Even if there will be more than one group across messages and they will be send to single consumer we can't parallell them locally without info to which grp they belong?

Comment: If the STOMP `MESSAGE` frame doesn't include any indication of the group then yes you'd be forced to process the messages serially. That said, I'd expect there to be some indication of the group in the frame. I know that in ActiveMQ Artemis the group is indicated with the `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` header.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this but after turning on dumping raw frames (in stompjs library) it seems that JMSXGroupID header is not sent with a message. Weird because custom user-defined headers are correctly sent with a message. For now I see only option to store group id in some custom header in addition to JMSXGroupID.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. You can either get a fix for this issue from the ActiveMQ community (or fix it yourself) or perhaps move to ActiveMQ Artemis.